# Amazon SES send email from domain without an smtp

Tags: amazon-ses

Is it possible with Amazon SES to send an email from say mycompany.com if there is no MX record for them.

I have setup Amazon SES and am waiting for DKIM to be verified and I am getting the error

```
{"Transaction failed. The server response was: Message rejected: Email address is not verified."}
```

I'm guessing this is just because the DKIM has not kicked in yet, but some of the things I'm reading seem to suggest that whatever email address is specified in the from for the message has to actually exist, ie. using no-reply@mycompany.com would not work.

So do you need to have a proper address/mx record setup for sending from any address for a domain or it is just a case of waiting for DKIM to kick in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Amazon SES works is you start in a sandbox environment before being switched to production. After you signup, Amazon verifies whether you own the email addresses as well as the domain of the sender. Whatever `from` address you are going to use, it has to exist and be verified. For more information, check the following link
  -[Verify address and domains guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html)

Comment: from what I can tell on that page it seems like if the domain itself is verified it doesnt matter if the account doesnt exist on the domain?

Comment: True. Either of the two works.